# Replace column name by Index

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, python-3.7

I have the below data in a Dataframe.

```
+----+------+----+------+
| Id | Name | Id | Name |
+----+------+----+------+
|  1 | A    |  1 | C    |
|  2 | B    |  2 | B    |
+----+------+----+------+
```

Though the column names are repeating, ideally, its a comparison of 1st 2 columns (old data) with the last 2 columns (new data).

I was trying to rename the 2nd last column by appending `_New` to it with Index using the below code. Unfortunately, the 1st column is also getting appended with `_New`.

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]: df.columns[2] + '_New'}, inplace=True)
```

Here's the result I am getting using the above code.

```
+--------+------+--------+------+
| Id_New | Name | Id_New | Name |
+--------+------+--------+------+
|      1 | A    |      1 | C    |
|      2 | B    |      2 | B    |
+--------+------+--------+------+
```

My understanding is that it should add `_New` to only the 2nd last column. Below is the expected result.

```
+----+------+--------+------+
| Id | Name | Id_New | Name |
+----+------+--------+------+
|  1 | A    |      1 | C    |
|  2 | B    |      2 | B    |
+----+------+--------+------+
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you always have 4 columns? What about Name, should the second get a `_New`? Are the columns always by pair? etc. give as much details as possible to define the best strategy

Comment: Yes, ideally Name should be also be renamed. For giving an example, I just mentioned only the Id column. If I get a solution for this, I can handle Name column in a loop

Comment: Probably dumb way would be - df.columns = ['Id',  'Name',  'Id_New',  'Name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple loop with a dictionary to keep track of the increments. I generalized the logic here to handle an arbitrary number of duplicates:

```
cols = {}

new_cols = []
for c in df.columns:
    if c in cols:
        new_cols.append(f'{c}_New{cols[c]}')
        cols[c] += 1
    else:
        new_cols.append(c)
        cols[c] = 1
df.columns = new_cols
```

output:

```
   Id Name  Id_New1 Name_New1
0   1    A        1         C
1   2    B        2         B
```

If you really want `Id_New` then `Id_New2` etc. change:

```
        new_cols.append(f'{c}_New{cols[c]}')
```

to

```
        i = cols[c] if cols[c] != 1 else ''
        new_cols.append(f'{c}_New{i}')
```

Comment: I was also thinking the same way if there is no direct Dataframe API available. Before I go with this approach I thought to ask in Stackoverflow to see if there are any alternatives. Thanks Mozway.